# dictionary values() method to show just few values

Tags: python, dictionary

*When I tried to run this line it type the follow error:* **TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable** *I want to see just the first 3 values of the dictionary*

`dict['Ages'] = {Ana:4, Eva:7, Paul:9, Ashley:2, Ken:12, Miley:23}`

`dict['Ages'].values()[0:3]`

I want the following answer:
{4,7,9}

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
d['Ages'] = {'Ana':4, 'Eva':7, 'Paul':9, 'Ashley':2, 'Ken':12, 'Miley':23}
list(d['Ages'].values())[0:3]
```

Explanation:

```
type(d['Ages'].values())
<class 'dict_values'>
```

`values` method returns the value of type `dict_values`. If you want to use slices you need to convert it to something that allow it - `List`, for example.

Comment: I get it as a list and I can slice it as well.I have checked both python and python3.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}

dict = {'Ana':4, 'Eva':7, 'Paul':9, 'Ashley':2, 'Ken':12, 'Miley':23}

for i, k in enumerate(dict.keys()):
    if i< 3:
        print(dict[k])
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. Remember to format code properly.